# Scrapinghub deployment error: non-exit status 1

Tags: scrapinghub

i get this error mesage when I try to deploy my project and I really do not understand why:[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjmya.png)

Comment: (here I'm in the spiders folder but this is not the problem, I also tried in all other folders)

Comment: does it give the very same error when you run it on the project folder?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes it does, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

shub is unable to build the Python egg of your project. This could be related to a misconfigured `setup.py`. Try running the 'build egg' command yourself so you can take a look at the error message: `python setup.py clean -a bdist_egg -d temp_directory` (run it in your project directory).

If you don't have any custom/important code in your `setup.py`, you can try deleting it, and shub will auto-generate a vanilla one on the next deploy.